# Why fwrite doesn't work for binary files in C?

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite

I want to write some data into a binary file, using C language. Apparently, the function fwrite doesn't seem to work properly. This is the code:

```
typedef struct tw {
    char name[40];
    char tweet[150];
    int rt, like;
} Twitter;

void createFile() {
    FILE *bin;
    Twitter user;
    if (bin = fopen("test.bin", "wb") == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(user.name, "name");
    strcpy(user.tweet, "this is a tweet");
    user.rt=5;
    user.like=10;

    fwrite(&user, sizeof(Twitter), 1, bin);

    fclose(bin);

}
```

The fwrite function doesn't write anything into the file, and I've looked for mistakes in the code, but I couldn't find any. Also, when I tried to use the function to write into a txt file, it worked correctly.

Comment: `return 0` should be `return`, since it's a `void` function.

Comment: And read your compiler warnings. They point out all the problems in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
if (bin = fopen("test.bin", "wb") == NULL)
```

to

```
 if ((bin = fopen("test.bin", "wb")) == NULL)
```

Comment: You should explain why the original code doesn't work, i.e. how it's being grouped.

Comment: Because `==` has a higher predecence than `=`, `bin` is not set to the file pointer, but to either 0 or 1, the result of the `==` comparison. If the file was successfully opened, `fopen() != NULL` and so `bin == 0` thus skipping the error report. However OP is then trying to call `fwrite()` with a file pointer of value 0 or NULL.